# Share database between two applications

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have created a database in App1. I want to access this database from App2. I want to use content providers for that. But I have a doubt. Where should I specify the content provider? Should I have the content provider in both App1 and App2 or just in App2?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following for that.

1. From your manifiest of application which contains database, expose your provider by specifying `exported=true`
2. Share the content URI which uniquely identifies your database, it will be Authority + database name with second application.

Now by using ContentResolvers your second app can query database from first applications, also to make it more secure you can  create your own custom permission and share that with your second app, in this case any other app in your phone wont be able to intrude over your database without proper authority.

Comment: So should i hv content provider in App1 ?

Comment: you can have it in any one of the app, and use above provided detail to enable sharing.